# how to implement uniqueConcatenate, uniqueCount in spark scala

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

I am trying to transform the data, the older code is in Tibco and using uniqueConcatenate, uniqueCount functions.

I am not sure how we can achieve same output in spark scala.

uniqueConcatenate Example:

[image]

uniqueCount Example:

[image]

I tried to use collect_set, but as i need to do Over partition by another columns, which seems like not be working for me.

Please help me here !

Answer (score 2):

For uniqueConcatenate you can use `collect_set()` function which aggregates a column into a set.
For example:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.{collect_set, concat_ws}
import spark.implicits._

case class Record(col1: Option[Int] = None, col2: Option[Int] = None, col3: Option[Int] = None)

val df: DataFrame = Seq(Record(Some(1), Some(1), Some(1)), Record(Some(1), None, Some(3)), Record(Some(1), Some(3), Some(3))).toDF("col1", "col2", "col3")

df.show()

/*
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   1|   1|
|   1|null|   3|
|   1|   3|   3|
+----+----+----+
*/

df.agg(
  concat_ws(". ", collect_set("col1")).as("col1"),
  concat_ws(". ", collect_set("col2")).as("col2"),
  concat_ws(". ", collect_set("col3")).as("col3")
).show()

/*
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|1. 3|1. 3|
+----+----+----+
*/
```

For uniqueCount, you can use `countDistinct` in a similar way:

```
import org.apache.spark.sql.functions.countDistinct

df.agg(
  countDistinct("col1").as("col1"),
  countDistinct("col2").as("col2"),
  countDistinct("col3").as("col3")
).show()

/*
+----+----+----+
|col1|col2|col3|
+----+----+----+
|   1|   2|   2|
+----+----+----+
*/
```

Comment: adding some more details:

my condition is something like -
uniqueConcatenate(col_1) over (col_2)

uniqueCount(col_3) over (col_4)

over seems i need to use WIndow function partitionBy column, the above both i tried but not getting expected output

Comment: The above snippets solves exactly what you asked. If you expect that people in StackOverflow will solve your tasks -- this is not the right place.

Comment: Sorry, but I am trying to take help from here for the problem which i am facing after many different trial. Thank you for your help and feedback.

Comment: Thank You!. I tried countDistinct earlier, for col which is having integer or bigint value, its working fine, but i have have varchar col i.e. example